# Symbolic coordinates with commas

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I use `symbolic x coords={}` with commas as decimal separators?

For example, I need to use `symbolic x coords={0,1.5,1.3}`, which gives full stops as decimal separators. Using `use comma` does not have an effect (logically, so I have nothing against that).

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={0,1.5,1.3},
    xtick=data,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (0, 1)
        (1.5, 2)
        (1.3, 1)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't seem to have the necessary version installed, so I can't check it, but my guess would be that you just have to enclose the numbers in braces, i.e. `symbolic x coords={0,{1,5},{1,3}}`

Comment: The `use comma` option works fine for me without `symbolic x coords`.

Comment: BTW, I just notice that you have a comma after `use comma` despite no options following. Maybe it works if you remove that?

Comment: @celtschk I am aware of that, but then I would have to enclose portions of the data as well, which is tedious and I can not reasonably automate it. The comma after `use comma` does not have an effect.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I know, but the symbolic coordinates are necessary (the _x_ axis corresponds to time and another quantity while the time is raising but the other quantity is changing in both directions).

Comment: @HarroldCavendish: That doesn't come out of your example (at least for me).

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I think that the first sentence is rather clear. I want to use symbolic coordinates with commas as decimal separators without altering the plot data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it is, PGFplots thinks that the symbolic coordinates are text strings, so it doesn't apply the number formatting options. To fix this, you can set `xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}`, which feeds the strings through the number parser and formats them accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={0,1.5,1.3},
    xtick=data,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}
]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (0, 1)
        (1.5, 2)
        (1.3, 1)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```